# Help me optimize this graph animation

Tags: android, graphics, animation

I need some help with this simple animation on my Android phone. I'm a newbie with animation and graphics.

I'm graphing accelerometer data as a sliding time series window. As new accelerometer data is read, its data is plotted on the right, pushing previous data to the left, as shown below:

[image]

My program is running pretty smoothly, but I would like some help optimizing the animation. Here are my main concerns:

1. My current implementation reads all the accelerometer data in one thread and keeps the data in a fixed-size FIFO queue to capture the width of the time series window. I then use Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate() to plot out the entire contents of the queue so that the whole graph is re-drawn every 50 milliseconds. Can I improve upon this? Do I really need to re-draw the graph so often like this? In another similar program I've seen, each pixel column is copied to one pixel to the left, rippling down the graph; the newest data's column is drawn on the far-right pixel column. Is this better?
2. I redraw the legend (in the upper left) in the drawing thread that runs the draw function every 50 milliseconds. Is there any way to "keep" that legend in place instead of having to constantly re-draw it?

Any other help would be appreciated. I have heard of optimizations like double-buffering but am clueless if that would help me.

Comment: You should perhaps consider to use 40ms instead. 50ms gives you 20fps, which is less than the eye will record. Thus the user might experience lag or aliasing. Providing your app manages 25fps, this should be a rule-of-thumb chosen framerate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the legend  and the cross hairs only need to be drawn once, then you should place it into a buffer bitmap. For your graph line maybe try using the Path object to plot the lines. When it gets time to draw the lines just drawLine to the appropriate point and then translate the canvas left appropriately.If

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on using a 'buffer bitmap' to store static content like the legend and cross hairs? I am not familiar with that technique. Also, regarding the translating the canvas, would that be faster than redrawing the graph?

Comment: I know it doesn't seem so, and I was shocked too. But for some reason, when I did all the math for my drawings it took a LOT longer than just translating canvas. As for the buffer, create a bitmap canvas pair and draw the legend and crosshairs into that. Then when you get your API canvas just draw the bitamp buffer on that canvas.

Comment: I'll try out the translation approach, thanks. Now, for the 'buffer bitmap', are you saying that I should just save the legend and crosshairs into a pre-drawn bitmap and paint it? If so, then paint still needs to be done in the View.onDraw() method that is constantly called to perform the animation, right? I was hoping that I could somehow 'fix' the legend and crosshairs and not have to keep redrawing them. Is this impossible?

Comment: You don't need to keep repainting the the bitmap once you have it drawn unless you want the paint to change. And unfortunately you will always have to draw the bitmap onto the canvas because you get a new canvas with every API onDraw(canvas) call. Fortunately keeping the legend and crosshairs as the bitmap will greatly improve the draw times (as opposed to completely redrawing it entirely everytime).

Comment: Look <a href="http://mindtherobot.com/blog/272/android-custom-ui-making-a-vintage-thermometer">here</a>. This is a brilliant tutorial on drawing stuff in android. Unfortunately is isn't graph based, but with the lessons gleaned from it, you can extrapolate all you need.